# Allowing users to create events on their own google calendar in flask app

Tags: python, flask, google-calendar-api, flask-sqlalchemy

I'm currently making an app for me and a few friends which will allow us to schedule events with our clients through the google calendar api.

Starting the app will require me to login/signup and then when I try to book a call, it will make me authorise it and the connection to google calendar(I used the google calendar quickstart docs)

Currently I have successfully been able to create the events and have them go onto my own calendar but when I test it with an alternate account, authorisation will not be requested and instead it will schedule the calls for the original account.

I believe this is due to the token.json file being created after authentication only being for the original account.

I was thinking of storing this json in a seperate column in my sqlalchemy database for each user but this is where i get a bit confused.

Any suggestions would be really helpful as to how to do this.

Comment: the question needs sufficient code for a minimal reproducible example:
https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: What are you confused about? Have you tried your approach and failed? Then explain what is the problem. Also, see [ask].